# Call c++ function pointer from c#

Tags: c#, c++, function-pointers

Is it possible to call a c(++) static function pointer (not a delegate) like this

```
typedef int (*MyCppFunc)(void* SomeObject);
```

from c#?

```
void CallFromCSharp(MyCppFunc funcptr, IntPtr param)
{
  funcptr(param);
}
```

I need to be able to callback from c# into some old c++ classes. C++ is managed, but the classes are not ref classes (yet).

So far I got no idea how to call a c++ function pointer from c#, is it possible?

Comment: I think your best bet is to create a C++/CLI wrapper for that.

Comment: This worked for me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790977/how-to-pass-a-delegate-or-function-pointer-from-c-sharp-to-c-and-call-it-there/39803574#39803574

Answer (score 17, accepted):

dtb is right. Here a more detailed example for Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer. It should work for you.

In C++:

```
static int __stdcall SomeFunction(void* someObject, void*  someParam)
{
  CSomeClass* o = (CSomeClass*)someObject;
  return o->MemberFunction(someParam);
}

int main()
{
  CSomeClass o;
  void* p = 0;
  CSharp::Function(System::IntPtr(SomeFunction), System::IntPtr(&o), System::IntPtr(p));
}
```

In C#:

```
public class CSharp
{
  delegate int CFuncDelegate(IntPtr Obj, IntPtr Arg);
  public static void Function(IntPtr CFunc, IntPtr Obj, IntPtr Arg)
  {
    CFuncDelegate func = (CFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(CFunc, typeof(CFuncDelegate));
    int rc = func(Obj, Arg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) method.

```
delegate void MyCppFunc(IntPtr someObject);

MyCppFunc csharpfuncptr =
    (MyCppFunc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcptr, typeof(MyCppFunc));

csharpfuncptr(param);
```

I don't know if this really works with your C++ method, though, as the MSDN documentation states:

> You cannot use this method with function pointers obtained through C++

Comment: The description says: "You cannot use this method with function pointers obtained through C++" - sadly, my function pointer is a c++ pointer.

Comment: Then your only option is, I guess, to create managed (ref) wrapper classes in C++ for your C++ library.