# Calling C# code from unmanaged C++?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

In Mono you can pass a delegate from C# to a C++ function which takes in the delegate as a function pointer. Can this be done in C# on Windows for example where you can compile a native C++ unmanaged library, link it against a C# project and get a C++ function to invoke a C# function via a function pointer which C# passed to it as a delegate?

Comment: it should be possible as we can inter operate between C# and c++. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2470487/1155650 check out this. maybe its what you are looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a delegate in .NET, and then pass that to your unmanaged code. The CLR will expose the delegate as a function pointer which you can call from your unmanaged code.

The interop layer does not know how to handle references in C++. So You need to expose the object as a pointer, not a reference. Additionally, .NET doesn't know what a C++
object is (it's not the same as System.Object). That will need to be passed
as an IntPtr, and I don't think there is much you can do with it in .NET.

C++ callbacks:

```
typedef void (*CBFUNC1)(unsigned int, const char*, object&);
typedef object* (*CBFUNC2)(object*, struct _mystruct* );
```

C# signatures for the delegates would be

```
delegate void CbFunc1(uint param1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string
param2, IntPtr param3);
delegate IntPtr CbFunc2(IntPtr param1, ref _mystruct param2);
```

Comment: yeah even with unmanaged C++ only that u have to provide your own Metadata for marshalling

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use C++/CLI to call into the C# code. If your C++ code must stay unmanaged (native), then you should wrap your C# code in a COM component and use it from your C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously can be done - all CLR hosts are native applications to start with. Your options:

- in managed application call your native DLL (PInvoke)
- call managed COM object (as Dan suggested)
- host CLR yourself - [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1481/Creating-a-host-application-for-the-NET-Common-Lan)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155650/rohit)'s answer is right, but there are lots more gotcha's on the path depending on whether you're calling back immediately (C# calls C++ which calls back C#) or if you want to call back repeatedly (C# calls C++ and after returning calls back one or more times later to C#).

i wrote [this example](https://github.com/natbro/UnityPlugin) from the perspective of Unity/C# and C/C++/Objective-C interop, but you may find some of the comments and code-snippets useful no matter where you are doing C#/C interop.

in particular make sure that you're propertly retaining/holding any delegates you pass from C#/managed to C/unmanaged code if the C/unmanaged code might be calling back at a different time.