# Calling Unmanaged C++ from C# (delegates)

Tags: c#, c++, com, delegates, c++-cli

This is similar to:

[Calling C# code from unmanaged C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731990/calling-c-sharp-code-from-unmanaged-c)

but the opposite.  I have some managed C#/C++CLI code that has triggering events.  (I don't have access to the code, just the dll).  I'd like to add my own C++ functions to be triggered on the events, but can't seem to get the typing right for them to be acceptable.

The dll specification for the type is a "public void delegate" which is not even valid (unmanaged) C++ syntax.  Yet the COM interface functions.

The type I need to be compatible with is  (from the .tlh file):

```
struct __declspec(uuid("72181a6f-4cc6-39aa-89d2-c8c4fd0cab3f"))
_RecordUpdatedDelegate : IDispatch
{};
```

All the other solutions for 'baking' a function pointer into a C# delegate involve having some access to the C# side.  I don't have that luxury.
I'm thinking this is either something someone has done many times or it is impossible.

Comment: So you have a COM event source written in C#, and need to know how to write a COM event sink in unmanaged C++?  If so, you will want to research "event sink" and "connection point" in relation to COM.

Comment: Update:  No real answer so far.  I can cheat by having a C++/CLI program, which I might end up doing, but it's not so pretty.

Comment: "All the other solutions for 'baking' a function pointer into a C# delegate..." Could you post a link to those solutions?

Comment: I haven't worked on that problem in quite some time.  But I remember it wasn't that bad.  You just needed to get the delegate to trigger some kind of (standard) C++ Observer.  It wasn't very hard, but there was a two step aspect to it.  I'll try to find a code fragment if I can,