# how can i talk with the C++ NPAPI dll in C#

Tags: c#, dllimport, npapi

I have an open source C++ DLL

actually it's a plugin dll from a CRX extension that i'm trying to call it's function in Visual Studio With C#

This extension is a Google chrome-screen-capture

I manage to create the Code that talked with the DLL But i have no idea how to call it's functions.

This is my CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        private class Sample
        {
            public Int32 length;
            public String value;
        }

        [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Ofir\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\screen_capture.dll")]
        private static extern void NP_Initialize();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sample s = new Sample();
            s.length = 0;
            s.value = "Huhu";
            NP_Initialize(); <-- I get an ERROR here : 
        }
    }
}
```

> ERROR : PInvokeStackImbalance was detected Message: A call to PInvoke
>   function
>   'ConsoleApplication1!ConsoleApplication1.Program::NP_Initialize' has
>   unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

What can i do?

**EDIT:** For Example if i use NP_GetEntryPoints() it will request a pointer with the type of NPPluginFuncs.

Exaple:`NPError WINAPI NP_GetEntryPoints(NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs)`

This is the type it's request:

```
typedef struct _NPPluginFuncs {
    uint16 size;
    uint16 version;
    NPP_NewUPP newp;
    NPP_DestroyUPP destroy;
    NPP_SetWindowUPP setwindow;
    NPP_NewStreamUPP newstream;
    NPP_DestroyStreamUPP destroystream;
    NPP_StreamAsFileUPP asfile;
    NPP_WriteReadyUPP writeready;
    NPP_WriteUPP write;
    NPP_PrintUPP print;
    NPP_HandleEventUPP event;
    NPP_URLNotifyUPP urlnotify;
    JRIGlobalRef javaClass;
    NPP_GetValueUPP getvalue;
    NPP_SetValueUPP setvalue;
} NPPluginFuncs;
```

But i have no idea how to build this type and send it.
I want to accomplish to build a function in IE toolbar and then use the functions in this DLL .
This way i can use the screen-capture in IE.

**EDIT2:** WHEN i'm calling the NP_Shutdown() function it's OK.
everything is clear and no exception is popping out.
so i guess it's all in the type that i send to the other function.
but how would i send this kind of type?

Comment: Is `NP_Initialize` supposed to take parameters? [It looks like it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NP_Initialize), and not passing it any when it's expecting them definitely will unbalance the stack. You can leave `CallingConvention` out of your `DllImport` - those functions are declared as `WINAPI`, meaning that the default calling convention is fine, and in fact using `Cdecl` will give you problems.

Comment: Ofear, if you really have `no idea`, then the best place to start is [the documentation on pinvoke marshalling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx). If you need help with a specific part of it, please update your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, my problem is to make this _NPPluginFuncs object and send this to the function...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I recently did some small excursion into NPAPI, so I share my findings. Though I cannot test your case, but I'd go this way.
Firstly declare a `_NPPluginFuncs` structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct _NPPluginFuncs
{
    UInt16 size;
    UInt16 version;
    IntPtr newp;
    IntPtr destroy;
    IntPtr setwindow;
    IntPtr newstream;
    IntPtr destroystream;
    IntPtr asfile;
    IntPtr writeready;
    IntPtr write;
    IntPtr print;
    IntPtr @event;
    IntPtr urlnotify;
    IntPtr javaClass;
    IntPtr getvalue;
    IntPtr setvalue;
    IntPtr gotfocus;
    IntPtr lostfocus;
    IntPtr urlredirectnotify;
    IntPtr clearsitedata;
    IntPtr getsiteswithdata;
    IntPtr didComposite;
}
```

Then declare PInvoke calls:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("C:\\Users\\Ofir\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\screen_capture.dll")]
private static extern void NP_Initialize(ref _NPPluginFuncs nPPluginFuncs);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("C:\\Users\\Ofir\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\screen_capture.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr NP_GetEntryPoints(ref _NPPluginFuncs nPPluginFuncs);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("C:\\Users\\Ofir\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\screen_capture.dll")]
private static extern void NP_Shutdown();
```

Finally, call the NPAPI:

```
_NPPluginFuncs nPPluginFuncs = new _NPPluginFuncs();
NP_Initialize(ref nPPluginFuncs);   // all members are 0 (IntPtr.Zero) after the call
IntPtr res = NP_GetEntryPoints(ref nPPluginFuncs);  // memory addresses filled in
NP_Shutdown();
```

Can you confirm if this works for you? There will be another big task ahead of you: calling those `IntPtr` functions that `NP_GetEntryPoints` returned...

Comment: Thanks you Peter Ivan for this answer.
 I will try to confirm this (it's an old project of mine.) But You deserve a few +1 just for this clean and helpful answer!

Comment: Hey Peter. I've followed this code and gotten the pointers from NP_GetEntryPoints. How do I go about calling my plugin functions though?

Comment: @Tsury: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470487) might help you on.