# How would this dllImport tag be formed?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dllimport

I've tried looking at similar questions, but have found no luck. I'm just confused on how to form this dllImport tag from a visual C++ dll that I created.

The prototype is:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WS_CreateComm(char *cAddress,void *Obj, void (*LogFunc)(void *, const char *, int, int, const char*, const char*, int, unsigned int))
```

how would I import it into my C# class?

Update:

This is what I've got so far:

```
delegate int CFuncDelegate(IntPtr Obj, string cErrorText, int iErrorLevel, int iTPM, string cFile, string cFunc, int iUserId, UInt16 iLineNumber);

    [DllImport("WatchService2DLL.dll")]
    public static extern void WS_CreateComm(string cAddress,void* Obj,CFuncDelegate func);

public static void Function(IntPtr CFunC, IntPtr Obj, string cErrorText, int iErrorLevel, int iTPM, string cFile, string cFunc, int iUserId, UInt16 iLineNumber)
    {
        CFuncDelegate func = (CFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(CFunC,typeof(CFuncDelegate));
        int rc = func(Obj,cErrorText,iErrorLevel,iTPM,cFile,cFunc,iUserId,iLineNumber);
    }
```

Is this implementation correct? How exactly do I call the WS_CreateComm now?

Comment: `unsigned int` is a `UInt32`, not `UInt16`.

Comment: ah, didn't catch that. thanks

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470487/call-c-function-pointer-from-c-sharp) as you need to marshal a function pointer.  For the char parameter a stringbuilder or a string is generally used.  The void* can be mapped as a long and I would set it to null as it most likely is passed back to you in the callback.